# How to find out the serial number of a reverse zone in bind?

Tags: linux, unix, bind

Is there a way to extract the actual serial number in effect for a reverse zone from a bind9 server?.

I can find out the domain's serial, but have no idea how to do the same for the reverse zones.

This is to find the serial for the my example.com domain (set up in example.zone in bind9):

```
# dig +nocmd example.com  any +multiline +noall +answer
example.com. 86400 IN SOA ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
                                2015013001 ; serial
                                86400      ; refresh (1 day)
                                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
example.com. 86400 IN NS ns2.example.com.
example.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.example.com.
example.com. 86400 IN A 10.2.2.22
```

How would I do the same for the reverse zones (set up in, for example, the 10.5.0.zone file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you do with a forward zone, by requesting the SOA record of the zone. For IP-address A.B.C.D the zone name is often C.B.A.IN-ADDR.ARPA but you can simply request the SOA for the host D.C.B.A.IN-ADDR.ARPA:

```
 dig SOA D.C.B.A.IN-ADDR.ARPA
```

And for your 10.5.0.x range:

```
 dig SOA 0.5.10.in-addr.arpa
```

For the Google public DNS resolver 8.8.8.8 you'll see this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> @4.2.2.1 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa SOA

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa.      IN  SOA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:                                             ;;  serial  refresh retry  expire  minimum
8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. 41  IN  SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 1580969 21600   3600   1209600 10800
```

Comment: This works just as well as my own answer and the command is more straight forward and easy to remember (less options). Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer right after posting the question, so I answer myself:

I found out this by looking at the log when restarting the bind9 server. Reverse zones are seen by the server as `<subnet.in.reverse>.in-addr.arpa`, so the 10.5.0 zone (from the 10.5.0.zone file) becomes the `0.5.10.in-addr.arpa` zone. So now I can just use the command on my previous post to find out the serial:

```
dig 0.5.10.in-addr.arpa  any +multiline +noall +answer  +nocmd
; <<>> DiG 9.5.0-P2 <<>> 0.5.10.in-addr.arpa any +multiline +noall +answer +nocmd
;; global options:  printcmd
0.5.10.in-addr.arpa.  86400 IN SOA mydomain.com. root.mydomain.com. (
                                2961345817 ; serial
                                86400      ; refresh (1 day)
                                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
0.5.in-addr.arpa.  86400 IN NS ns1.mydomain.com.
```